# counting monomials and integrality

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, polynomials, discrete-mathematics, enumerative-combinatorics

For $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, consider the polynomials
$$P_n(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x^n-x^k).$$

> **QUESTION.** Is it possible to find a closed formula for the number of monomials in $P_n(x)$, after expansion?

Those interested in such enumeration may like to [read this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.3652.pdf).

Here is an assertion which might be possible to prove.

> **CLAIM.** For any $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, the following are all integers:
>   $$\frac1{n!}P_n(m).$$

**UPDATE.** If it helps, I've found a stronger divisibility when $m$ is a prime $p$.

$$\frac{P_n(p)}{n!\,\cdot p^{\eta_p(n)}}=\frac{p^{\binom{n}2}\prod_{k=1}^n(p^k-1)}{n!\,\cdot p^{\eta_p(n)}}$$
where $\eta_p(n)=\nu_p\left((p\lfloor n/p\rfloor)!\right)$ and $\nu_p(m)$ is the [$p$-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of an integer $m$.

Comment: So the present question is about proving the claim, and not the enumeration, isn't it?

Comment: Both are seeking solution and proof.

Comment: thank you. I see the sequence is listed in OEIS as http://oeis.org/A086781 with no closed formula reported

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: In the OEIS entry, Emeric Deutsch notes a slightly simpler definition, which is much faster computationally.

Comment: @MartinRubey: True, which is explained by $Q=x^{\binom{n}2}\prod_{k=1}^n(x^k-1)$.

Comment: The claim is true and well-known (if $x$ is a prime powers, the ratio is a number of bases in $\mathbb{F}_x^n$).

Comment: So the enumeration question is equivalent to: given $n$, for how many integers $k$ the number of representation of $k$ as a sum of an even number of distinct  positive numbers not larger than $n$ is equal to the number of representation of $k$ as a sum of an odd number of distinct positive numbers not larger than n? (because we are interested in the number of non-zero  coefficients, and all of them are  $n(n+1)/2+1$ )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is correct. We begin with a standard lemma.

**Lemma:** Let $p$ be an odd prime, and $x$ an integer coprime to $p$. Let $k$ be a positive integer and let $o$ be the multiplicative order of $x$ modulo $p$. Then $$v_p(x^k-1) = \begin{cases} v_p(x^o-1) + v_p(\frac{k}{o}) & o \mid k \\ 0 & o \nmid k \end{cases}.$$

We prove the claim by comparing the [$p$-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of $P_n(m)$ and $n!$ for every prime $p \le n$ (since all prime divisors of $n!$ are $\le n$). We skip the primes in the set $\{ q: q \mid m \} \cup \{2\}$ (they may be treated separately). The lemma implies that your claim is equivalent to the following inequalities:
$$(*) \forall p\le n (\text{odd, coprime to }m): v_p((\frac{n}{o})!) + \lfloor \frac{n}{o} \rfloor v_p(m^o-1) \ge v_p(n!),$$
$$\text{where }o \text{ is the multiplicative order of m modulo p},$$
and slightly different inequalities for $p=2$ and $p \mid m$.

We have:
$$v_p((\frac{n}{o})!) + \lfloor \frac{n}{o} \rfloor v_p(m^o-1) \ge v_p((\frac{n}{o})!) + \lfloor \frac{n}{o} \rfloor  = \sum_{i \ge 1} \lfloor \frac{n}{op^i} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{n}{o} \rfloor$$
$$= \sum_{i \ge 1} \lfloor \frac{pn}{op^i} \rfloor \ge \sum_{i \ge 1} \lfloor \frac{n}{p^i} \rfloor = v_p(n!), $$
where the last inequality follows from the fact that $o<p$. This proves $(*)$.

To deal with the exceptional primes ($2$ and divisors of $m$), just note that $P_n(m)$ is divisible by $m^{\binom{n}{2}} (m-1)^n$ and that $v_p(n!)\le n,\binom{n}{2}$ for every $p$ and $n$.

Comment: Interesting. Up-voted.

Comment: For some years, I've been interested in a non-prime-counting proof of this one. Anyone?

Comment: What are you referring to when you said "of this one"?

Comment: Of the divisibility claim that Ofir has proven.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Good question. I have a lead, maybe you can complete it. For prime power $q$, $P_n(q)$ counts elements of the set $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, on which $S_n$ acts freely by permuting rows. Hence the divisibility follows for prime powers. I wanted to proceed by showing that if $P(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ assumes a non-integer value on some $x=m \in \mathbb{Z}$, then necessarily exists an arithmetic progression $a \bmod b$ with $(a,b)=1$ on which $P$ assumes only non-integer values, and (cont. in next post)

Comment: (cont.) ... then to use Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions. By taking $a=m,b=\text{Common denominator of coefficient of }P$ we can find easily an arithmetic progression on which $P$ doesn't assume integer values, but it doesn't necessarily satisfy $(a,b)=1$.

Comment: I've tried this and it leads nowhere. There are polynomials taking integer values at all prime powers but not at all integers.